# Service Fabric approach for images uploading

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I have special `Images` stateless Reliable Service for images uploading. It uploads content to the Azure Blob Storage and returns back an url for uploaded item. Also my project has `ApiGateway` stateless Reliable Service with `OwinCommunicationListener` and authorization endpoint for API users. I want to add a new endpoint for authorized users allows to upload images in storage.

What is the most effective and the fastest way to do it?

I have two suggestions and do not know which is the best:

1. Add a new endpoint to my `ApiGateway` Reliable Service, create proxy for Images stateless Service and pass arrived data to it for uploading.
2. Create an `OwinCommunicationListener` on my `Images` staless Reliable Service with external endpoint.

In first case it looks like it takes more time than in the second. Because I need to spend some time for passing data between services. In the second case I do not spend time for transporting and just wait until my Azure Table Storage finished with uploading. But the major disadvantage of this approach is the fact that I need to configure authorization for `Images` `OwinCommunicationListener` and make sure it handles external authorized requests correctly.

Comment: How about issuing sas tokens from your image service and having the clients upload straight to a blob in a container? This will avoid you having to move the data around and save money. Downside is that you won't have control over the uploaded size. More on sas: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/

Comment: @LoekD good solution, but it doesn't answer my requirements. I have some business logic in `Images` service (resizing, compressing) before I load an image to the storage.

Comment: Can't that be done in a post-processing run? (like in a webjob with a blob trigger for instance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past when doing something similar - I've used an APIGateway to

1. Authorize the request
2. Store a reference against the file with a GUID
   in the db
3. Return a URL where the client needs to post the file (see below)

With the Azure Blob API you should be able to create a custom signed request (URL) that allows the client to upload directly to blob storage but with limited permissions such as

1. Only upload the file the exactly filename
2. File must be uploaded within X hours

The client device then uploads directly to the Azure Blob.

This has been the best approach in terms of security and performance.

This is a good starting point:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/delegating-access-with-a-shared-access-signature

Answer (score 0):

The API gateway can just accept the request(image). Then it will call a reliable service that will store the image in file(local to cluster or another blob storage),  add the request(image with identifier) in the Reliable Queue, then return the identifier (Guid) to the API gateway.

Have a process in the reliable service that checks for items in Reliable queue and process it by calling the stateless service to do image processing, store the images in Azure Blob storage, and return back the URL to statefule service. The stateful service will store the result (URL)in Reliable Dictionary (with the identifier).

The API gateway can re-query the reliable service if the identifier is in the reliable dictionary. Should be fast depending on number of stateless services in cluster to process the images.

Comment: Great solution, but as I mentioned already, it binds us to transport issue. You need to send picture between you API Gateway and Reliable Service responsible for uploading. Thats basically why I am asking about is it a good approach, or not? I would like to decrease transporting data with encapsulating uploading Reliable Service and API together in one special Images API service.